# How to read csv file from resources dir in JUnit Test using FileUtils

Tags: java, apache-commons, apache-commons-io, apache-commons-csv

Have a csv file inside a standard maven project's resources dir as follows:

```
src/main/resources/fruits.csv
src/test/resources/fruits.csv
```

fruits.csv

```
Type, Quantity
apple, 50
banana, 60
orange, 70
```

Using the following libraries

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Fruit (standard POJO)

```
public class Fruit {

    private String type
    private int quantity;

    public Fruit(String type, int quantity) {
        this.type = type;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    // Getters & Setters
}
```

CsvFileReader

```
public class CsvFileReader {

    private static final String [] FILE_HEADER = {""};

    private static final String TYPE = "Type";
    private static final String QUANTITY + "Quantity";

    public static List<Candidate> readCsvFile(File fileName) {
        FileReader fileReader = null;
        CSVParser csvFileParser = null;

        CSVFormat csvFormat = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withHeader(FILE_HEADER);
        List<Candidate> fruits = null;
        try {
            fruits = new ArrayList<>();
            String file = FileUtils.readFileToString(fileName);
            fileReader = new FileReader(file);
            csvFileParser = new CSVParser(fileReader, csvFormat);
            List<CSVRecord> records = csvFileParser.getRecords();

            for (int i = 1; i < records.size(); i++) {
                CSVRecord record = records.get(i);
                Fruit fruit = new Fruit(record.get(TYPE), Integer.parseInt(QUANTITY));
                fruits.add(fruit);
            }
        } 
        catch(Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        } 
        finally {
            try {
                fileReader.close();
                csvFileParser.close();
            } catch(IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return fruits;
    }
}
```

CsvFileReaderTest (JUnit 4 Test Case):

```
public class CsvFileReaderTest {

    File csvFile = null;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        String userDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        String filePath = userDir + File.separator + "src" + File.separator + "main" + File.separator + "resources" + File.separator;
        csvFile = FileUtils.getFile(filePath + "fruits.csv");
    }
}
```

When I run the JUnit Test Case inside Eclipse:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Type, Quantity
apple, 50
banana, 60
orange, 70
(File name too long)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:101)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:58)
```

It seems to reading the file but the problem is that the FileName is too long?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The whole point of storing files under src/main/resources (or src/test/resources) is to have the file available as a resource in the runtime (resp. test) classpath, and to ba able to load it with the ClassLoader. Use `SomeClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/fruits.csv")` to get an InputStream over the resource. Don't use file IO.

Comment: I assume the POJO is just an example, right? Because the constructor is missing the type for the second argument

Comment: Vogel612 - thanks for pointing that out - I made the appropriate edits. @JB Nizet, are you stating that I should run the JUnit test via maven instead of running it through Eclipse?

Comment: @socal_javaguy I don't see anything in my comment that indicates that.

Answer (score 0):

`FileReader` constructor expects a path to file where you pass a **content** of the file. You may use directly `CSVParser` constructor which takes CSV `String`.

```
csvFileParser = new CSVParser(file /*This is already file content*/, csvFormat);
```

** Edit **

Even better would be to obtain reader for the resource and pass it to CSVParser constructor:

```
reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                       this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("fruits.csv")));
csvFileParser = new CSVParser(reader, csvFormat);
```